# Need help resolving error in SOLR 6.0.0 related to dataimport handler with MongoDb

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, solr

Hi I am trying to explorer mongodb and solr.

using a solr6.0.0 i have configure data import handler

1. added lib solr-mongo-importer-1.1.0.js, mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.js, solr-dataimporthandler-6.0.0.js

**solr-6.0.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib**

I have copy  solr-mongo-importer-1.1.0.js and mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.js

**solr-6.0.0\server\lib**

I have copy  solr-mongo-importer-1.1.0.js and mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.js

"dist" folder have solr-dataimporthandler-6.0.0.js and solr-dataimporthandler-extras-6.0.0.js.

I have created core "abc"

solr-6.0.0\server\solr\abc\conf\solrconfig.xml

```
 <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />


 <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

**at data-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="MyMongo" type="MongoDataSource" host="localhost" port="27017" database="TEST"/>
    <document name="Document">
        <entity name="Subscriptions" processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
             query="{ 'Email' : 'test@test.com' }"
             collection="Subscriptions"
             datasource="MyMongo"
             transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" >
            <field column="id" name="id" mongoField="_id"/>
           <field column="Email" name="Email" mongoField="Email"/>    
           <field column="SubmittedFor" name="SubmittedFor" mongoField="SubmittedFor"/>    
           <field column="DateCreated" name="DateCreated" mongoField="DateCreated"/>    

        </entity>     
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

After that I was stop solr and start again.

With core "abc" at dataimport, i am able to see dataimport handler.
From dropdown select entity and check commit and clean option.
Clicking execute button its show 0 request, 0 fetch, 0 process

I am look at cmd its show error as output when we execute dataimport

```
Exception in thread "Thread-23" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/
handler/dataimport/EntityProcessorBase
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoade
r.java:487)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:530)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:467)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.ja
va:924)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapp
er(DocBuilder.java:721)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java
:214)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImpo
rter.java:416)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.j
ava:480)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.ja
va:461)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.
EntityProcessorBase
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 26 more
```

Mongo Db structure

collection name "Subscriptions"

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5684e03420f1640c10ba0ca3"), 
    "Email" : "javiyamahesh@yahoo.com", 
    "SubmittedFor" : "MonthlyNewsletter", 
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2015-12-31T08:20:02.531+0000")
}
```

I have try to search on internet but not found any help about this error.

Comment: hello, I am having the same issue, any solution?